# Which one is better to use Sencha Touch or phonegap for android?

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, sencha-touch-2

I have searched many articles on `Sencha Touch and Phonegap` but i was unable to judge `which framework is the better to integrate` while developing my Android App. and even i got many stuffs on difference between `Sencha Touch and Phonegap` but it was not enough to recognize which is better framework to use.
   So plz any one tell which is good to use. `Sencha Touch OR Phonegap`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask

Answer (score 22):

You are asking about 2 completely different frameworks.

**Phonegap** is only a wrapper framework around other HTML5 GUI frameworks. It can only be used to create a hybrid mobile application and to give it ability to access different phone functions.

On the other hand **Sencha** Touch is a HTML5 framework for rich web applications that can also be used to create a hybrid mobile application. Sencha can also be packaged with Phonegap, so again you can see they are different frameworks made for different purposes.

Only way **Phonegap** can compete with **Sencha** is if you use it with some other HTML5 framework like **jQuery Mobile**. So basically your question is should I use **Sencha** Touch or **Phonegap** + some HTML5 framework.

My advice would be, if you have time learn and use **Sencha** Touch. It alone works better than **Phonegap** + **jQuery Moible**. If you want to find out more about Sencha Touch and jQuery Mobile difference take a look **[here](http://www.gajotres.net/sencha-touch-vs-jquery-mobile/)**. BUT, you will spend much more time learning how to create a **Sencha** Touch app while **jQuery Mobile** can be learned much much faster. Also **Phonegap** has a HUGE set of plugins so if you planing to create something more complex they I would advise you **Phonegap** approach.

If you want to give PhoneGap and jQuery Mobile a chance take a look **[here](http://www.gajotres.net/building-a-native-mobile-app-with-phonegap-and-jquery-mobile-1-4/)**, currently last jQuery Mobile version is pretty fast, still not as fast as Sencha Touch but it is finally usable with Phonegap.

You can always go even further, why limit your self with Sencha Touch or jQuery Mobile, even PhoneGap has competition.

There are two excellent article discussing differences among 14 (7 + 7) different HTML5 mobile frameworks:

- [**TOP 7 MOBILE APPLICATION HTML5 FRAMEWORKS**](http://www.gajotres.net/top-7-mobile-application-html5-frameworks/)
- **[TOP 7 NOTABLE LESS KNOWN MOBILE HTML5 FRAMEWORKS](http://www.gajotres.net/top-7-notable-less-known-mobile-html5-frameworks/)**

Comment: +1 for link as this question is asked more frequently.

Comment: Thanks,
1. can you update?, taking in consideration a MVC approach ? I heard Sencha Touch is for MVC, and jQuery Mobile not so much...

2. you mention the time, but maybe using Sencha will become faster as the project grows, while jQuery always take the same time, since the code can't be reused too much... what do you think?