# can any one differentiate sencha touch, jquery mobile and phonegap?

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-mobile, sencha-touch

I am developing a mobile app. can any one differentiate sencha touch, jquery mobile and phonegap? which one to be used?

Comment: I have found [something](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16398788/which-one-is-better-to-use-sencha-touch-or-phonegap-for-android) that I want to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sencha Touch is a framework for building web application for touch UI and controls. It is very useful for mobile application embedded with Native Wrapper like Phonegap.

Jquery mobile is similar to Sencha Touch but originated from desktop mobile friendly usage and can be used for mobile application (it is necessary you optimize some controls for good touch response on android devices). It has some responsive widgets embedded as well. I have used it for some mobile applications with phonegap.

Twitter bootstrap is a framework for collection of friendly control which can be used across different flavours of application.

Specific to your question, since you are developing asp.net website, you can use some free responsive framework to achieve your needs, [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/),[Simplegrid](http://simplegrid.info/) are good options. Alternatively, if you are sound in css3, you may write advanced css to achieve this (may be time consuming)